# JSONObject getString if statements

Tags: android, json

String result = "{\"error_type\":\"success\",\"message\":\"Error Message....."}";

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);
if( (json.getString("error_type") == "error") {
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Test", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
} else {
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Nooo", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

This code is Toasting "Nooo". But json.getString("error_type") is a "error". What is this problem ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should test `String` equality using the `equals` method instead of `==`. i.e.,

```
if (json.getString("error_type").equals("error")) {
  ...
}
```

the `==` operator compares object references and not the contents of the `String` itself.